# How to send parameters from JS function to python mthod in odoo?

Tags: javascript, python, odoo-9

Here is the JS line which invokes Python method

```
model_obj.call(FunctionToBeCalled,active_id,{context:self.dataset.context})
```

And here is my python method,

```
@api.multi
def delete_client_analysis_profile(self):
    print 'self',self
    query = "delete from olims_analysis_profile_olims_client_rel where olims_analysis_profile_id in("+\
        ",".join(str(record.id) for record in self)+")"

    self.env.cr.execute(query)
```

I am unable to get the `active_id` in my python method. Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

To call your method from `js` use:

```
new instance.web.Model("your.model")
.call( "delete_client_analysis_profile", [[active_id]])
    .then(function (result) {
        // do something with result
});
```

Then you need just to manipulate `self`.